# Print depending on variable value

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I need to determine whether `F` exists. If `F` exists, then the belt is a *"V-belt"*, if not, it is a *"horizontal belt"*.

Here's my code

```
F=input

if F exist
    fprint('V belt')
else
    fprint('Horizontal belt')
end
```

Basically, I also don't know what I write.

Comment: Is this the actual code you wrote?

Comment: Fa=input('Enter the value of Fa:');
if Fa==0
    fprint('Ball Bearing')
else
    fprint('Roller Bearing')
end

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/exist.html), e.g.

```
if exist(F,'var')
    foo;
else
    bar;
end
```

Ok, due to your comment I would suggest:

```
F = [];
while isempty(F)
    F = input('Enter the value of Fa: ');
end

if F == 0
    % ...
else
    % ...
end
```

Comment: I think of this, but still cannot be executed. Need help to modify.

Comment: 'Fa=input('Enter the value of Fa:');
if Fa==0
    fprint('Ball Bearing')
else
    fprint('Roller Bearing')
end'

Comment: That is because for `input` the return values is empty but exists in the bad case. Just use `isempty` instead.